# Problem Installing to Azure China

Tags: azure

Sitecore 9.2

I am trying to run an ARM Template to install Sitecore to Azure China. I set the location parameter to "China East 2".  When I run Start-SitecoreAzureDeployment, it creates the resource group properly in my Azure.cn instance, however then it then throws the error:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 3:03:44 PM - Error: Code=LocationNotAvailableForResourceType; Message=The
provided location 'westus' is not available for resource type 'Microsoft.Search/searchServices'. List of available
regions for the resource type is 'chinaeast2'.
At C:\Projects\mts.com\scripts\AzureInstall\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:120 char:35
+ ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep
   loymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : The deployment validation failed
At C:\Projects\xxxxxx\scripts\AzureInstall\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:120 char:35
+ ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep
   loymentCmdlet
```

It looks like the installation script is ignoring the location parameter and always installing to "westus" instead of using the parameter passed to Start-SitecoreAzureDeployment.  How do I get around the westus location?

Comment: I'm not sure about the error message here, but you should take a look at the Azure Compatibility table: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/617478

China regions are missing a lot of dependent services (like Azure Search which your error is about)

Comment: In addition to Jason's message, please check how are you setting China East 2 in your parameter, give a shot by adding chinaeast2 instead